# Search object in array and update if exist or add

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is what my array of logged in users looks like:

```
const connectedUsers = [{
  user: {
    uuid: 'b62-2dw',
    points: 1,
  },
  id: "1234567"
}];
```

I will concat this table when a new user logs in to my system:

```
this.connectedUsers = [
  ...this.connectedUsers,
  {
    ...payload,
    id: client.id
  },
];
```

Then my array looks like this: (I give this to better understand)

```
const connectedUsers = [{
    user: {
      uuid: 'b62-2dw',
      points: 1,
    },
    id: "1234567"
  },
  {
    user: {
      uuid: '663-dda',
      points: 5,
    },
    id: "33332"
  }
];
```

If the user with the uuid like `663-dda` updates his point, I perform this method again.
When I leave it as it is, something like this will be done:

```
const connectedUsers = [{
    user: {
      uuid: 'b62-2dw',
      points: 1,
    },
    id: "1234567"
  },
  {
    user: {
      uuid: '663-dda',
      points: 5,
    },
    id: "33332"
  },
  {
    user: {
      uuid: '663-dda',
      points: 6,
    },
    id: "33332"
  }
];
```

I want to **write a very nice (use ES6+)** algorithm that first checks if such an object exists in this array (check by `id` or by `user.uuid`). If so, update. If not, add a new object. So it should be like this:

```
const connectedUsers = [{
    user: {
      uuid: 'b62-2dw',
      points: 1,
    },
    id: "1234567"
  },
  {
    user: {
      uuid: '663-dda',
      points: 6,
    },
    id: "33332"
  }
];
```

Comment: please add **your** try.

Comment: Why not try using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead?

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you're updating the array when a user logs in, you could do like this:

```js
if (!this.connectedUsers.find(user => user.user.uuid === payload.user.uuid) {
  this.connectedUsers = [
    ...this.connectedUsers,
    { ...payload, id: client.id },
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const connectedUsers = [{
            user: {
                uuid: 'b62-2dw',
                points: 1,
            },
            id: "1234567"
        },
        {
            user: {
                uuid: '663-dda',
                points: 5,
            },
            id: "33332"
        },
        {
            user: {
                uuid: '663-dda',
                points: 6,
            },
            id: "33332"
        }];
//let take some sample object

const newObDuplicateUuid = {
            user: {
                uuid: '663-dda',
                points: 6,
            },
            id: "3333290"
        }
        
const newObDuplicateId = {
            user: {
                uuid: '756-dda',
                points: 6,
            },
            id: "33332"
        }
        
const newObFresh = {
            user: {
                uuid: '756-dda',
                points: 6,
            },
            id: "3333290"
        }

let checkRule = connectedUsers.every(item => item.user.uuid != newObDuplicateUuid.user.uuid && item.id != newObDuplicateUuid.id)

//return false for same uuid

checkRule = connectedUsers.every(item => item.user.uuid != newObDuplicateId.user.uuid && item.id != newObDuplicateId.id)

//return false for same id

checkRule = connectedUsers.every(item => item.user.uuid != newObFresh.user.uuid && item.id != newObFresh.id)

//return true
console.log('Passed validation :'+checkRule);

const result = checkRule ? [...connectedUsers,newObFresh] : 'There is duplicate value';

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach. One function that covers both cases. Just pass the `array` and the `new entry` and it will return the `updated list`

```js
function updateOrAddUser(listOfUsers, newEntry) {
    let found = false;

    const updatedUserList = listOfUsers.map(entry => {
        if (entry.user.uuid === newEntry.user.uuid) {
            found = true;

            return newEntry;
        }

        return entry;
    });

    if (!found) {
         updatedUserList.push(newUser);
    }

    return updatedUserList;
}
```